# ¿Cómo aceder a los argumentos de argv[1] en un tabla?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un [código de Vigenere](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrado_de_Vigen%C3%A8re) que está la generalización del código de Caesar con un desplazamiento que varía por cada letra del texto a cifrar. Es por decir, cada letra del texto con el código ASCII c<sub>i</sub> la cambiaré en c<sub>i</sub> = (p<sub>i</sub> + k<sub>j</sub>) % 26.

Se ejecuta como eso:

```
./vigenere bacon
que esta el texto a cifrar
Meet me at the park at eleven am
Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz
```

Sin embargo, si era capaz de cifrar con el código de Caesar, tengo dificultades con el código de Vigenere. La encoriación está muy particular y no da letras:

```
:~/workspace/pset2 $ ./vigenere bacon
Que esta ek texto a cifrar?
Meet me at the park at eleven am
m@T @ � T@  � @
```

Aquí está mi código:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    string key = argv[1];

    printf("What is the text to be encrypted?\n");
    string s = GetString();
    int encryptedASCII[strlen(s)];

    for (int i = 0, o = strlen(s); i < o; i++)
    {
        if(i==o)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (int j = 0, p = strlen(key); j < p; j++)
        {
            if (isalpha(s[i]))
            {
                if(isupper(s[i]))
                {

                    encryptedASCII[i] = (((s[i] - 'A') + key[j])%26) + 'A';
                    if(j==p)
                    {
                        j=0;
                    }

                }

                if(isupper(s[i]))
                {

                    encryptedASCII[i] = (((s[i] - 'a') + key[j])%26) + 'a';
                    if(j==p)
                    {
                        j=0;
                    }

                }
            }

            else
            {
                encryptedASCII[i]=s[i];
                //j--;
            }

        }

    }

    //here we are displaying the encrypted text 
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", encryptedASCII[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Pienso que el error esta aquí: `string key = argv[1];` Quiero crear una tabla con los letras de la clave de cifrado que varía por cada letra a cifrar.

Pienso que hay que acceder a las letras que ya están en `key[j]` (que, sin embargo, fue declardo como `string key = argv[1];`). Pero ya no sé cómo acceder al código ASCII de una letra en una tabla...

### puesto al día

Pues, he traido la idea de eferion, cambio los bucles for y la applicacion de la clave a las letras con esta formula: `+ key[i%strlen(key)])%26`

```
El nuevo codigo esta:

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{

    char* key= argv[1];
    /*int ASCIIvalue[strlen(key)];

    for (int u = 0, q = strlen(key); u < q; u++)
    {
        ASCIIvalue[u]=key[u];
    }*/

    printf("What is the text to be encrypted?\n");
    string s = GetString();
    int encryptedASCII[strlen(s)];

    for (int i = 0, o = strlen(s); i < o; i++)
    {
        if(i==o)
        {
            break;
        }

        char ckey = key[i%strlen(key)];
        int Ikey;
        if(isupper(key[i%strlen(key)]))
        {
            Ikey= ckey -'A';
        }
        else if(islower(key[i%strlen(key)]))
        {
            Ikey = ckey -'a';
        }

        if (isspace(s[i]))
        {
                        encryptedASCII[i]=s[i];
        }

        else if (isalpha(s[i]))
        {

            if(isupper(s[i]))
            {
            //char ckey = key[i%strlen(key)];
            encryptedASCII[i] = ((s[i] - 'A' + Ikey) % 26) + 'A';

            }

            if(islower(s[i]))
            {
            //char ckey = key[i%strlen(key)];
            encryptedASCII[i] = ((s[i] - 'a' + Ikey) % 26) + 'a';
            }
        }

        else
        {
            encryptedASCII[i]=s[i];
            //j--;
        }

    }

    //here we are displaying the encrypted text 
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", encryptedASCII[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Este funciona hasta el primer espacio que, es una lástima, esta tenido en cuenta, lo que desplaza la encriptación.

```
$ ./vigenere bacon
What is the text to be encrypted?
Meet me at the park at eleven am   
Tegh ne og tjs qaty bt syfvgb bm
```

pero debe ser:

```
Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz
```

En efecto, **tenemos que disociar la variable `i` de la variable que se pasea por la clave**

Answer (score 2):

Hay que empezar diciendo que `string` es un alias de `char*` definido en la librería `cs50.h`.

`char` es un entero de 8 bits que el compilador traduce en un carácter usando una tabla ASCII, pero realmente es un número y por ello puedes realizar operaciones matemáticas con el. Si quieres visualizar el número que hay detrás puedes optaro por convertirlo a int.

```
int ASCIIvalue = key[i];
```

### puesta al día

Tu nueva versión adolece de varios problemas

```
if (isalpha(s[i]))
{
  if(isupper(s[i]))
  {
    encryptedASCII[i] = (((s[i] - 'A') + key[i%strlen(key)])%26) + 'A';
  }

  if(isupper(s[i]))
  {
    encryptedASCII[i] = (((s[i] - 'a') + key[i%strlen(key)])%26) + 'a';
  }
}
```

¿El segundo condicional no debería ser `islower`?

Por otro lado estás asumiendo que la clave va a estar en mayúsculas... ¿Qué sucede si el usuario introduce parte de la clave en minúsculas?

Quizás lo más sencillo sea convertir tanto la clave como la entrada del usuario a mayúsculas y después lanzar un único proceso de cifrado:

```
void toUpper(char* ptr)
{
  for(; ptr!=0; ++ptr)
    *ptr = toupper(*ptr);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char* key= argv[1];
  toUpper(key);

  printf("What is the text to be encrypted?\n");
  char s[100];
  scanf("%s",s);
  toUpper(s);

  int encryptedASCII[strlen(s)];

  for (int i = 0, o = strlen(s); i < o; i++)
  {
    if (isalpha(s[i]))
    {
      char ckey = key[i%strlen(key)];
      encryptedASCII[i] = ((s[i] - 'A' + ckey) % 26) + 'A';
    }
    else
      encryptedASCII[i]=s[i];
  }

  //here we are displaying the encrypted text 
  printf("%s\n", encryptedASCII);
}
```

Otra alternativa sería convertir el caracter de la clave a mayúsculas/minúsculas de tal forma que coincida con el carácter a cifrar pero esa versión corre de tu cuenta.

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Entonces he escrito:     char* key= argv[1];
    
    `    char* key= argv[1];
    int ASCIIvalue[strlen(key)];
    
    for (int u = 0, q = strlen(key); u < q; u++)
    {
        ASCIIvalue[u]=key[u];
    }`

Y cambio la formula: `encryptedASCII[i] = (((s[i] - 'A') + ASCIIvalue[j])%26) + 'A';` Pero siempre tengo un output muy extraño:

`$ ./vigenere bacon
What is the text to be encrypted?
Meet me at the park at eleven am
m �� ��  n   
 @W`

Comment: Si `key` tiene longitud 5 y tu intentas cifrar un mensaje de longitud 15 está claro que no vas a poder hacer `key[6]`. ¿Has probado con `key[j%strlen(key)]`?

Comment: Si, da lo mismo. Pero quiero que el key se reitera cuando se acaba. ¿Quiere que añado el nuevo codigo?

Comment: Eso mismo es lo que pretende hacer el módulo en el código de mi comentario anterior...

Comment: He entendido y añadido el nuevo código

Comment: ¡Gracias por su ayuda! Este codigo funciona por las primeras mínusculas, sin embargo tiene cuenta de los espacios y, por lo tanto, deplaza el codigo. No funciona por las mayúsculas...
`Meet me at the park at eleven am:    
Tegh ne og tjs qaty bt syfvgb bm` mientras que deberia ser: `Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz` He cambiado mi secundo código.

Comment: En el tema de los espacios piensa que la idea no es hacerte la tarea sino resolver tus dudas (son dos cosas bastante diferentes). En cuanto a las mayúsculas, tendrás que ser más específico porque has tocado el código y desconozco su estado actual.

Comment: Lo que está claro es que no solo tienes que tener en cuenta si `s[i]` está en mayúsculas o minúsculas... esto tienes que hacerlo coincidir con `key[i]`. No puedes tener una `s` en minúculas y una `key` en mayúsculas o viceversa porque entonces va a funcionar mal.

Comment: Entiendo. Pero quiero que cuando doy la clave `bacon` quiero que funciona para cadas letras. Es por decir que qualquier sea la primera letra, se desplaza de uno por la derecha en el alfabeto. Es por eso que he cambiado un poquito su formula para normalizarle en termas matemáticas. Además, he añadido mi último código

Comment: Okay, ahora funciona para las mayúsculas pero no funciona cuando el primer espacio esta encontrado.

Comment: El foro es para resolver dudas, no para hacer los deberes de clase. Intenta no caer en la tentación de preguntar absolutamente todo y trata de buscar primero una solución propia. Aprende a usar el depurador de código, herramienta imprescindible donde las haya. Además piensa que una vez que modificas tu código lo que figura en la pregunta del foro deja de ser válido porque ya no se corresponde con tu programa actual. Un saludo

Comment: @KeineLust hasta donde se 1 byte = 8 bits. Y piensa que a veces una respuesta canónica  no es fácil de entender por la persona que pregunta.  En cualquier caso eres libre de añadir tus propias respuestas si crees que las que hay publicadas no son lo suficientemente buenas

Comment: @KeineLust te he escrito en el chat para no llenar esto de comentarios

Comment: Disculpa pero no puedo acceder al chat, puede que no tenga suficiente reputación.

Comment: De todos modos es una cuestión poco importante, es muy difícil encontrar arquitecturas en las que 1 byte != 8 bits o codificaciones EBCDIC fuera de sistemas embebidos (y no creo que sea el caso), lo que si me parece importante es dejar claro que `char` es un entero y punto, con "y punto" no pretendía ser brusco, solo matizar eso: `char` es un entero "sin más"

Comment: @KeineLust [enlace al chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) Hasta donde se para acceder al chat no hace falta más que 20 puntos de reputación...

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a enferion por toda la ayuda, aqui esta el  código de Vigenere que funciona con minúculas y mayúsculas, y tenga en cuenta los espacios

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int j= 0;
    char* key= argv[1];

    printf("What is the text to be encrypted?\n");
    string s = GetString();
    int encryptedASCII[strlen(s)];

    for (int i = 0, o = strlen(s); i < o; i++)
    {

        if(i==o)
        {
            break;
        }


        if (isalpha(s[i]))
        {
            char ckey = key[(j%strlen(key))];
            int Ikey;
            if(isupper(key[j%strlen(key)]))
            {
                Ikey= ckey -'A';
                j++;
            }
            else if(islower(key[j%strlen(key)]))
            {
                Ikey = ckey -'a';
                j++;
            }

            if(isupper(s[i]))
            {
            //char ckey = key[i%strlen(key)];
            encryptedASCII[i] = ((s[i] - 'A' + Ikey) % 26) + 'A';

            }

            if(islower(s[i]))
            {
            //char ckey = key[i%strlen(key)];
            encryptedASCII[i] = ((s[i] - 'a' + Ikey) % 26) + 'a';
            }
        }

        else
        {
            encryptedASCII[i]=s[i];
            //j--;
        }

    }

    //here we are displaying the encrypted text 
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", encryptedASCII[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```